# Bézout ring with non-trivial Picard group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, projective-module, free-modules

A ring is called *Bézout* when its finitely generated ideals are principal.

> **Q**: Is there a nice example of a Bézout ring $R$ with a non-free rank $1$ projective $R$-module?

Below are some thoughts and motivation:

Until recently I had assumed (and thought I had a proof in mind) that any Bézout ring would have trivial Picard group.  But then I came across the paper [Finitely Generated Modules over Bézout Rings](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102905697) of Wiegand and Wiegand, in which **Theorem 2.1 implies that any Hermite ring $R$ which is not an elementary divisor ring contains an element $d$ such that $R/(d)$ has nontrivial Picard group**.

However, I'm pretty sure that it's at least the case that any Bézout ring with compact minimal prime spectrum (with respect to the Zariski topology) will necessarily have a trivial Picard group.   *Reasoning*: first reduce to the case that $R$ is a reduced ring, since that affects neither the Picard group nor the compactness of $\operatorname{minSpec}(R)$. Then observe that $R$ will have Von Neumann Regular total ring of fractions $T(R)$ (using Bézout and compactness assumptions). Since Von Neumann Regular rings have trivial Picard groups, deduce that every rank 1 projective of $R$ is isomorphic to an ideal of $R$ which is invertible in $T(R)$.

So in looking for an answer to **Q** I'm looking in the subset of Bézout rings which have non-compact minimal prime spectrum and which aren't elementary divisor rings.  I've been having trouble coming up with anything explicit under these constraints.  Most of the still-viable candidate Bézout rings I know occur as rings of continuous real-valued functions on the remainder of certain Stone-Čech compactifications.  I find it hard to work with such rings under construction.  For example, if we take $X$ to be the union of the positive x-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the positive half of the $\sin$ curve, and take $R = C(\beta X \setminus X)$ (the ring of associated real-valued continuous functions), then $R$ is Hermite but not an elementary divisor ring (cf example 4.11 [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1956-082-02/S0002-9947-1956-0078980-4/S0002-9947-1956-0078980-4.pdf)), so the above-cited Theorem 2.1 implies that $R/(d)$ would provide me an example for some $d \in R$. Yet I have no idea how to locate such an element $d$ or, having done that, what this projective module would look like.  Since I've apparently been carrying around this misconception about Picard groups of Bézout rings for quite a while, I'd love to have an explicit example to sink my teeth into.

Comment: Crossposted on MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345798/b%c3%a9zout-ring-with-non-trivial-picard-group